# CLI running gradle dependencies task of multiple projects

Tags: gradle, dependencies

- I'm trying to *automate* `gradlew dependencies` for *multiple* projects
- I want to use the `--scan` option for web output.
- The problem is that I need to type `yes` for the license agreement every time.

```
$ for ...; do cd ...; ./gradlew dependencies --scan; done
```

Trying to redirect a `yes` answer in advance doesn't work:

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies --scan < "yes"    // bash: yes: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid accepting the license via command line by adding the following code to your `build.gradle` file:

```
gradleEnterprise {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
        termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
    }
}
```